# How can I use nltk to get resonse

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am going to get response from nltk.
I don't have any idea for this.

If you have a source code or reference link, please share it.
I tried myself several time but it was failed.

Answer (score 1):

I found one link for this question.
https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chat/eliza.html